# SQL IF Statement or Flag using 2 Tables

Tags: sql, if-statement, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables (1 main table and 1 supplementary table) with ID #'s on each table.  Some ID #'s appear on both tables and some don't.  I need to flag/new field (named Both) which shows if the ID # appear on the supplementary table and the main table.

I am new to SQL and know of IF statements but haven't had much success using with it using more than 1 table.

**Main Table**

```
ID#   | Fruit                       
1     | apple                        
2     | peach                       
3     | orange
4     | pear
```

**Supplementary Table**

```
ID#    | Fruit
 3     | orange
 4     | pear
```

Any help would be appreciated!
-Newb

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.  The expect outcome is a new field that simple has a Y or No (1 or 0) titled 'Both' so that when I look up the specific ID #, I know it's on both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `left join` and then a `case` expression on the ID of the supplementary table:

```
SELECT    m.id, 
          m.fruit,
          CASE WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS both
FROM      main m
LEFT JOIN supplementary s ON m.id = s.id
```